# Java - Efficient approach for keeping single instance collections

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency, singleton

I have multiple lists and maps (concurrent ones). I need to keep these collections as single instances. They are going to be modified by multiple threads and they will be accessible from other objects.

Should I create a thread-safe singleton class and keep all these collections as private fields with getter methods? Is it a good approach? Any other alternative solution? Or should I keep these collections as public static instances in their meaningful entity java beans?

**Option 1:** Keeping collections in singleton instance.

Entity:

```
package com.anilaltunkan;

import java.util.List;

public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private int age;
    private double salary;
    private List<String> addresses;

    //getters and setters
    //.
    //.
    //.
}
```

Singleton:

```
package com.anilaltunkan;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton INSTANCE = null;
    private final List<Employee> employeeList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Employee>());
    private final Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Employee>();

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                if(INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployeelist() {
        return employeeList;
    }

    public Map<String, Employee> getEmployeeMap() {
        return employeeMap;
    }

}
```

**Option 2:** Keeping collections in java bean instance and remove singleton class

```
package com.anilaltunkan;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private int age;
    private double salary;
    private List<String> addresses;

    private static final List<Employee> employeeList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Employee>());
    private static final Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Employee>();
}
```

**Option 3:** Keeps collections in static Utility class

```
package com.anilaltunkan;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Utility {
    private Utility() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    public static final String SOME_CONSTANT = "AA";
    public static final List<Employee> employeeList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Employee>());
    public static final Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Employee>();
}
```

Comment: Without any more details this is too broad and vague to be answered here.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: There's not much difference between static instance and a singleton, it's some statics anyway.

Comment: I would keep an instance which happens to be created once and pass it via dependency injection. I would try to avoid using a mutable static field if possible (though it's not always possible)

Comment: Please be more specific and describe your use case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

1. Will employeeList and employeeMap be modified together in one atomic operation? then it's better to create a wrapper class, say, Employees and handle concurrency from there.
2. If employeeList and employeeMap don't care about each other, then use Concurrent implementations of list and map and inject them separately.

   Although I'm guessing that scenario 1 is what you need.

PS: don't use singleton, just create one instance in main or factory, then inject them. If you're framework is not allowing that, then try exploring DI containers, those will handle Singletons for you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Peter's suggestion, you can use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead of synchronizing ArrayList with wrapper.